# Msgbox warning popup when cell A1 is "Yes" and cell A2 is left blank

Tags: vba, excel

Does anyone know how to get a msgbox popup when for example cell A1 is "Yes" and cell A2 is left blank? I want to apply to all of column A. So If A3 is "Yes" and A4 is blank, another msgbox. All the odd rows will be where there is a Yes/No dropdown and even rows will be where there can be comments. Thanks!

Comment: Your users will hate you for bombarding them with Messageboxes. Better mark the cells e.g. with a red background, and prevent whatever comes next in your workflow from happening.

Comment: That's true haha. I think I'm adding way too many popup. Do you know how I can include perhaps a red outline of the cell if this condition happens?

Comment: `If Trim(LCase(Sheets("sheetname").Range("A1").Value)) = "yes" And Len(Trim(Sheets("sheetname").Range("A2").Value)) = 0 Then Sheets("sheetname").Range("A2").Interior.ColorIndex = 3`

Comment: Why you need VBA, it can be done by IF function in conditional formatting to highlight cells where condition is True/False.

Comment: For VBA You need to use sheet module macro "Private Sub Worrksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)".  "Target" is the cell that was changed by the user, and "Target.Address" comes in the form of "$A$1". so you can use an if statement to determine if the changed cell was in column "A" by "IF instr(1, Target.Address, "$A$") then" - and you can add what ever code you need there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting this macro into your worksheet module.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Left(Target.Address, 3) = "$A$" And UCase(Target) = "YES" And Range("B" & Target.Row) = "" Then
        Range("B" & Target.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    End If
    If Left(Target.Address, 3) = "$B$" And UCase(Range("A" & Target.Row)) = "YES" And Target <> "" Then
        Range("B" & Target.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You could also use "IF Target.Column = 1" to represent column A.